# React checkbox group is not being updated with the state

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, react-state-management

Hi I an using this state for the checkbox group

```
  const [ socialLists, setSocialList ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSocialList([
      { name: 'Facebook', checked: true },
      { name: 'Twitter', checked: true },
      { name: 'Instagram', checked: true }
    ]);

  }, []);
```

The checkbox is initially checked, I am updating the state with an onChange function on my checkboxes, but it the `checked` value is not being updated.
This is my jsx

```
<FormGroup row>
              {socialLists.map((social) => (
                <FormControlLabel
                  key={social.name}
                  control={
                    <CustomCheckbox value={social.name} checked={social.checked} onChange={filterScheduleData} />
                  }
                  label={social.name}
                />
              ))}
            </FormGroup>
```

This is the onChange function

```
  const filterScheduleData = (event, checked) => {
    const checkboxes = socialLists;
    checkboxes.forEach((i) => {
      if (i.name === event.target.value) {
        i.checked = checked;
      }
    });
    setSocialList(checkboxes);
  };
```

In the end the list is being updated but the checkbox value does not change with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your filterScheduleData, you need to duplicate socialList before modifying it:

```
const checkboxes = [...socialLists];
```

Otherwise you're just creating a reference to the socialList array which you cannot change directly because it is state